# Chrome extension manifest v3 exclude_glob and exclude_matches not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've got 2 scripts that I want to load depending on what site ppl open in browser ...
**login.js** should only be loaded on admin.someDomain.com, admin.someOtherDomain.com and localhost
**dc_ctre_content.js** should be loaded on all other pages opened in browser.
Now, **login.js** is correctly added, but **dc_ctre_content.js** is also added to admin.someDomain.com, admin.someOtherDomain.com and localhost domains and it shouldn't be!
Since I'm developing locally my local address is "http://localhost:5090/something" maybe that's the problem.
from **manifest.json v3:**

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["*://admin.someDomain.com/*","*://admin.someOtherDomain.com/*","*://localhost/*"],
    "js": ["js/login.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
},
{
    "exclude_globs": ["*://admin.someDomain.com/*","*://admin.someOtherDomain.com/*","*://localhost/*"],
    "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"],
    "js": ["js/dc_ctre_content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}
],
```

I've also tried with **exclude_matches** but no joy.
Any help appreciated on how to not load dc_ctre_content.js script on excluded domains.

Regards

Comment: I've put apache proxy server in front of my java server on port 5090, now it works. dc_ctre_content.js is not loaded to page ... but the docs say that ports are includedd !!! #fml

Answer (score 1):

this fixed it
`"exclude_globs": ["http://localhost:*/*"]`
I had to put :* after host name for this to work properly.